# Painel de medalhas na aba participação no perfil de usuário

Tags: bug, status-recusado, layout

Na "próxima medalha" (à direita) o cursor está padrão (`auto`), seria melhor o `pointer`, não me recordo mas acredito que era assim antes, agora pouco queria saber mais sobre essa medalha mas não tava conseguindo porque, como não estava com o cursor "isso é clicável", fiquei só passando o mouse por cima. Percebi que dava pra clicar porque a "recentes" (à esquerda) está com o cursor correto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No de privilégios acontece a mesma coisa; obs: @AndersonCarlosWoss, qual software usou para o gif?

Comment: @Barbetta [Peek](https://github.com/phw/peek)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventualmente vamos precisar de fazer mudanças maiores e restruturar os perfis. Podemos corrigir este tipo de bug então, mas sendo muito pequeno vamos recusá-lo por agora.

---

At some point we need to do major work on restructuring profiles. We can fix this type of bug then, but since it is very minor we will status-decline it for now.