# Diferença entre as tags status-futuro e status-recusado

Tags: debate, tags, meta-tags

Na wiki da tag [status-recusado](/questions/tagged/status-recusado):

> Esta tag é usada para designar tanto:
>
> - Recurso de pedidos que não serão implementados no tempo presente
> - E bugs que não serão corrigidos agora.
>
> Ela apenas pode ser adicionada ou removida pelos moderadores e os desenvolvedores do site.

Em relação ao segundo item, qual a diferença para a tag [status-futuro](/questions/tagged/status-futuro)?:

> Esta sugestão tem mérito, mas não é a coisa muito prioritária na nossa lista.
>
> Vamos tentar chegar a ele.
>
> Esta tag só pode ser adicionada ou removida pelos moderadores e desenvolvedores do site.

Pela frase "E bugs que não serão corrigidos **agora**.", entendi que vai ser feito mas não no presente momento, e a resposta [nessa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7225) pergunta que fiz, reforça essa ideia

Não deveriam estar juntos? Ao meu ver faz mais sentido já que ambas dão a entender que é algo que vai mudar no futuro (apesar da diferença de importância)

Comment: Uma não será feita, outra será feita um dia. Não entendi porque estariam juntas.

Comment: "E bugs que não serão corrigidos **agora**." Pelo que entendi vai ser feito mas não no presente momento, e a resposta  [nessa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7225/painel-de-medalhas-na-aba-participação-no-perfil-de-usuário) pergunta que fiz, reforça essa ideia

Comment: Elas são antagônicas.

Comment: Acho que são meio que "isso não nos interessa agora" e "isso nos interessa, mas não faremos agora"; a primeira não implica que um dia será feito.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, ainda sim, não faria mais sentido ficarem juntas? Apesar da diferença de importância, ambas dão a entender que é algo que vai mudar no futuro

Comment: Na pergunta que usas como exemplo, @GuilhermeCostamilam, foi usado o `recusado` porque ainda que o que reportaste na publicação venha a ser trabalhado/corrigido no futuro, provavelmente não há-de ser nos contornos que o perfil de utilizador actualmente tem — o que foi dito é que daqui a uns tempos se vão mudar muito mais coisas nos perfis, e portanto isso também há-de ser corrigido. Espero ter feito sentido? :)